# Loop array content value consist of single value and array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have tried to loop this array but I still get error

I have an array like this:

```
1 => ["name"=>"A", "related"=>[
["signal"=>"A1", "color"=>"green"],
["signal"=>"A2", "color"=>"lime"],
["signal"=>"A3","color"=>"yellowGreen"]
]] 
2 => ["name"=>"B", "related"=>[
["signal"=>"B1", "color"=>"Red"],
["signal"=>"B2", "color"=>"Pink"]
]]
```

How to display as  - A : Green, lime, yellowGreeb
                   - B : Red, Pink

This is my code that I've tried to display as above format

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
  echo $value["name"];
  foreach($value["related"] as $k){
    echo $k["color"] . ",";
  }
}
```

It throw error this array dont has $value["related"] index. But It can echo the $value["name"]???

Thank you!

Comment: what is your error and how do you get the "- B: Red, Pink" when it's nowhere in your array?

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my post!

Comment: @QUANGTRAN see updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution as below:

```
$array = [1 => [
    "name" => "A",
    "related" => [
        ["signal" => "A1", "color" => "green"],
        ["signal" => "A2", "color" => "lime"],
        ["signal" => "A3", "color" => "yellowGreen"]
    ]
],
    2 => ["name" => "B", "related" => [
        ["signal" => "B1", "color" => "Red"],
        ["signal" => "B2", "color" => "Pink"]
    ]]
];

foreach ($array as $ar) {
    $new_arr = array_column($ar['related'], 'color');
    $required_string = implode(', ', $new_arr);
    echo $ar['name'].' : ' .$required_string;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

For PHP Version < 5.5 you can use below solution:

```
foreach ($array as $ar) {
    $new_arr = array_map(function ($value) {
        return  $value['color'];
    }, $ar['related']);
    $required_string = implode(', ', $new_arr);
    echo $ar['name'].' : ' .$required_string;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

you can found more detail about `foreach` loop at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: This'll work within `PHP > 5.5` versions only. [Check This](https://3v4l.org/dc2VB)

Comment: yes for older version you need to change syntax of array.. `$array = array(1 => ...)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :D